# Add CPLEX to Octave on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, optimization, octave, cplex

I'm on Ubuntu, when I want to add Clpex functions to octave so I can use Cplex functions, using **addpath()** to pass the folder path as below :

```
>> addpath('/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1210/cplex/matlab/x86-64_linux')
```

The command is valid with no errors, then I enter the Cplex command to check that Cplex has been added, I get the following **error** :

```
>> Cplex 
   error: class not found: dynamicprops
```

Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: I see nothing on CPLEX Documentation https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/pdf/gscplexmatlab.pdf saying that is Octave compatible

Comment: furthermore, if you type 'dynamicprops' on octave, it will inform you that this function exists in matlab, but is not yet implemented in octave. At the very least this means you will not be able to get Cplex to work with octave, without a significant overwrite and lots of debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both comments to the question are correct:

1. CPLEX does not have octave support
2. dynamicprops is not implemented in octave.

Given that the CPLEX matlab API depends on dynamicprops, it will not work in octave as is.

However, you can try a workaround: first install https://github.com/farhi/octave-dynamicprops. It is not a drop-in replacement for matlab's dynamicprops, but may be sufficient. CPLEX uses dynamicprops for handling parameters, so if you do not modify any parameters then octave-dynamicprops may give you just enough to get cplex working. Of course, even if this works now it may break down in the future...

Good luck!